# Error in starting MySQL in Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: mysql

i am trying to run MySQL 5.5.8 in my Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard).
I'm calling /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe and I get this in the error log...

```
110124 16:35:36 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql-5.5.8-osx10.6-x86_64/data
110124 16:35:36 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql-5.5.8-osx10.6-x86_64/data/ is case insensitive
110124 16:35:36 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
110124 16:35:36  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
110124 16:35:36  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
110124 16:35:36  InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
110124 16:35:36  InnoDB: 1.1.4 started; log sequence number 2809411
110124 16:35:36 [ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Permission denied
110124 16:35:36 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /var/mysql/mysql.sock ?
110124 16:35:36 [ERROR] Aborting

110124 16:35:36  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
110124 16:35:38  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 2809411
110124 16:35:38 [Note] /usr/local/mysql-5.5.8-osx10.6-x86_64/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

110124 16:35:38 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql-5.5.8-osx10.6-x86_64/data/MyMacPro.local.pid ended
```

Here is what I have in /etc/my.cnf... wondering if I need to add more settings.

```
[client]
socket = /var/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
socket = /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Thank you so much,
Robert

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> 110124 16:35:36 [ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Permission denied
> ```

We did the following just now with MySQL 5.5.28 that fixed the bind problem for us.  It is necessary because the sock file is written here:

```
sudo chown -R _mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

We also did the following although I'm not sure that it was necessary:

```
sudo chown -R _mysql /usr/local/mysql
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sudo cp /usr/local/mysql/support-files/my-small.cnf /etc/my.cnf
$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
.... SUCCESS!
```

This done it for me!

Answer (score 2):

From what I remember, Mac OS X's /var/mysql will be owned by root by default, so there are two solutions to this problem.

1. Start mysql as root by prepending your command with `sudo`, e.g. `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe`
2. Or change the /var/mysql directory to be owned by yourself, since you're running the mysqld_safe command. This would be done as follows: `sudo chmod -R yourusername:yourgroup /var/mysql`

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you're using option two, make sure /var/mysql exists as a directory too, and create it if necessary.

Comment: i have used sudo in calling the mysqld_safe... the error above came out from the error log... /usr/local/mysql/data/MyMacPro.local.err ..

Comment: It's `sudo chown -R yourusername:yourgroup /var/mysql`, but thanks a lot for the pointer anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem. Something went wrong with my installation via mac ports.

```
Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Permission denied

Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock ?
```

Check if you can read/write to `/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/` with the `mysql` user:

```
sudo -u mysql touch /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/test
sudo -u mysql ls l /opt/local/var/run/mysql5
```

If not, check the permissions in the parent folders. In my case `/opt/local/var/run` had strange permissions 730 (`drwx-w----`) but should have been 755.

Answer (score 1):

You could install the MySQL Preference Pane, as detailed [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/macosx-installation-prefpane.html). 
This would allow you to control MySQL without root privileges.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are executing this as normal user. Run the same command using sudo and then following the command you are using.

Comment: also see if you have existing process running: $ ps -ax | grep mysqld

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem in mysql 5.5.8 installation on MAC snow leopard,you can use mysql 5.1.56 instead & it works fine for me.The complete installation steps are mentioned here on this blog http://mysqlonsnowleopard.blogspot.com/ just follow the steps & it works

Answer (score 0):

We've document installing MySQL and PHPMyAdmin in Mac OS X [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BhsQNwP_ndPM0-EecYPtpXvgl16hFK_fnV_FBm77S2Q/edit).